# How to remove the extra space which is occurred because of Scroll View at the bottom of layout in android?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, space

The Scroll View is generating the extra space in layout file. How to remove extra space?

[image]

Comment: post your layout file, please :)

Comment: Please give more info such as a screenshot and so on.

Comment: Most likely it is because you have the horizontal scroll bar enabled. In your ScrollView tag in your layout.xml put this line `android:scrollbars="none"`

Comment: Yes please it would be helpful if u post the layout file content.Although u can find yourself what is taking up the space using DDMS tool in eclipse or android studio which ever u are using and capture the screen content.Then moving our mouse over the the contents will display the which component is of how much width and height

Comment: anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`android:scrollbarStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarStyle) to your `ScrollView`.

For your use case, you might want to use `insideOverlay` or `outsideOverlay`